# How to create TCP/IP message queue using Vb scripting UFT?

Tags: vbscript, message-queue, tcp, hp-uft

I am a beginner in UFt VB Scripting.
I have existing  Java code which creates a TCP/P Queue from Windows system and send it to Linux Server .

Below is the Java code snippet:-

```
cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);


cf.setQueueManager("MSGSVCSD");
                URL url = new URL("file:\\C:\\Users\\TestQueue\\MSGSVCSD.TAB");
                cf.setCCDTURL(url);

Queue q = session.createQueue("XXXX.XXXX.OUTPUT");
                producer = session.createProducer(q);
```

I want to create a similar Queue and have tried with below code snippets:-

```
Set MQSess = CreateObject("MQAX200.MQSession")
Set QMgr = CreateObject("MQAX200.MQQueueManager")
```

But hings are not working for me , i am not sure in parameter what need to be passed.

Comment: I am not sure UFT and VBs are the tools for that. Why don't you take a try with the DotNetFactory Global Object. This one lets you create .NET Objects from any library that is installed in the Global Assembly Cache of .NET. That should be much easier as yoiu have a lot of Libraries there

Comment: You mean Vbscript and UFt is not rich in Message Queue libraries ?

Comment: Exactly. with the help of DotNetFactory you have much better chances.